# Function statement requires a Name in Services in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a demo app. I want this AngularJS app to have factory as well.

I keep getting error: "SyntaxError: function statement requires a name"

Below is my code:

```
var bookApp = angular.module('bookAppModule',[]);    

bookApp.controller('boookbAppCtrl', ['$scope','$http',Book ,
  function($scope,$http,Book) {

    $scope.way=["Normal","$http","RestFul"];

    $scope.books = 
    [
    {"title":"abc","author":"zxc"},
    {"title":"def","author":"cvb"},
    {"title":"ghi","author":"nml"},
    {"title":"jkl","author":"kjh"},
    {"title":"mno","author":"fds"}
    ];

    var names=["Anuj","Donvir"];  

    $scope.newbooks = Book.getBooks;


  }]);                                                  


bookApp.factory('Book', 
  function(){

      getBooks : function(){
        return 
         [
            {"title":"newbook1","author":"zxc"},
            {"title":"newbook2","author":"cvb"},
            {"title":"newbook3","author":"nml"},
            {"title":"newbook4","author":"kjh"},
            {"title":"newbook5","author":"fds"}
         ];

      }

  });
```

Comment: It needs to be `['$scope','$http','Book',` (notice the quotes around `Book`) - it's no different than the other services you inject, strings of their names, then parameters. The items before the function in the array need to be strings, as names of services. Then the parameters in your function represent those strings, and can be named anything (usually you just match them up). Also, depending on what you are trying to do with `$scope.newbooks = Book.getBooks;`, I think you meant to use `$scope.newbooks = Book.getBooks();`

Comment: Ian is right you must have quotes in you annotation which is the `Book`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your factory, you forgot to write the overall return function that returns all the 'methods' in the service.

```
 bookApp.factory('Book', 
  function(){
  return { // you did not have this return, only its body
      getBooks : function(){
        return 
         [
            {"title":"newbook1","author":"zxc"},
            {"title":"newbook2","author":"cvb"},
            {"title":"newbook3","author":"nml"},
            {"title":"newbook4","author":"kjh"},
            {"title":"newbook5","author":"fds"}
         ];

        }
     }    
  });
```

**Addition**
Also, to add on the above reason which caused the error, personally i battled for many days with a similar error in angular services. It was caused by the overall `return` function not being in the same line with the `{` that contains the body of the `return`. See below.

```
// will cause the error
 bookApp.factory('Book', 
      function(){
      return 
      { // { below not on same line with return
          getBooks : function(){
           // ...
          }
      }    
     });

// will not cause the error
 bookApp.factory('Book', 
      function(){
      return { // { on same line with return
          getBooks : function(){
           // ...
          } 
      }   
      });
```

I do not know the exact reason for this behaviour but what i know is that when you use them on same line, it will work and you will not have to stall your project like i did many times.

Comment: You forget to the closing `}` of the returned objects (in all cases), but other than that, this should be the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to forget the position of the braces, you can define this angular factory using Revealing Module Pattern  as like this...

```
  bookApp.factory('Book', 
  function(){

      var factoryServices=
      {
            getBooks: getBooks
      };

      return factoryServices;

      function getBooks()
      {
        // ...
      }

  }
```

});

For more reading: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y052